# IBM Worklight - How to send post values in adapter?

Tags: java, json, rest, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I'm using rest service. My service accepts Employee object as an input for my JSON Post request. I'm using worklight adapter to call the service. Can any one help me in writing an example of how the code looks like.

**Sample:**
public class Employee{
String id;
String name;
String address;
...
...

}

@Post
@Consumes(JSON)
@Produces(JSON)
public ResponseObject getSomeInfo(Employee emp){
.......

}

Can any one help me with the code to write this adapter request?

Answer (score 3):

I don't really understand what your question is asking, but if you are attempting to write a POST request inside a Worklight adapter you should start by reading the documentation around Worklight Adapters:

Adapter Framework Overview:
http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/04_01_Adapter_framework_overview.pdf

HTTP Adapter:
http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/04_02_HTTP_adapter_-_Communicating_with_HTTP_back-end_systems.pdf

Invoking Adapter Procedures From the Client:
http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/04_06_Invoking_adapter_procedures_from_client_applications.pdf

As a quick example I can show you the structure of a really basic POST request adapter:

```
function postSomeInfo(Employee emp){   
     var input = {
          method : 'post',
          returnedContentType : 'application/json',
          path : path,
          body:{
              contentType:'application/json',
              content: emp.id
          }   
     };  
     return WL.Server.invokeHttp(input); }
```

Looking at your method above it seems you are trying to create a GET method though (getsSomeInfo). Can you please elaborate on your question further if this does not help solve it.